# How to get drupal custom profile values?

Tags: drupal

There is a checkbox added in user profile form, subscribe to daily newsletter. I want to get list of users who have subscribed (checkbox ON) and send them daily newsletter. How can I do this in drupal-6. (1) to get list of all subscribed users (2) Send them Email.

If you can explain at code level, I 'll really appreciate that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your profile field is profile_newsletter, your :

```
<?php
  function mymodule_get_subscribers() {
    $query = 'select * from {profile_fields} where `name`="%s";';
    $result = db_query($query,'profile_newsletter');

    $field = db_fetch_object($result);

    $user_query = 'select * from {profile_values} where `fid`=%d and `value`=1;';
    $result = db_query($user_query,$field->fid);
    $subscribers = array();

    while($subscriber = db_fetch_object($result)) {
      $subscribers[] = $subscriber->uid;
    }

    return $subscribers; // Your array of subscriber user IDs
  }
?>
```

This code was quick, is untested and should probably contain a few sanity-checks. But it should work.

For the sending of newsletters and such I'd recommend using a pre-rolled module. I haven't tried any for Drupal, but Simplenews seems to do the trick. http://drupal.org/project/simplenews

If nothing else it probably contains a good sending-function. Otherwise just use PHP mail()-function.

Comment: Just chiming in to say thank you as well. This pointed me in a good direction!

Answer (score 0):

```
function your_custom_function ($user_id, "Field you want to get") {


      $result = db_query("SELECT t2.value FROM profile_fields t1, profile_values t2 where  

    t1.title='Field you want to get' and t2.uid=".$user_id." and t1.fid=t2.fid");

                    $field = db_fetch_object($result);

                    $profile_type =$field->value;

                    return $profile_type;
               }
```

Comment: Using this function you can get single profile field value, so we can avoid using separate module to get profile fields as token